# Proving statement for a tree-graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, trees

So i need help with this:
Let T be a tree.
And degree of every vertice is an odd number.
So i need to prove that there is an odd number of paths in that tree.

So i basically need to prove that there is an even number of vertices.

So probably i could use a method like this:
Let $$|V(T)|= x$$ and let x be an odd number, so i want to get into a contradiction.
Is that the correct way 
Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is pretty easy:

In any  tree $T$ we have
$$ |V(T)|= |E(T)|-1$$
where |E(T)| is the number of edges in $T$

Note that 
$$|E(T)|=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{v\in T} d(v) $$
Then we have two case

1- $ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{v\in T} d(v) $ is odd and thus $ |V(T)|$ is even

2-  $ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{v\in T} d(v) $ is even and thus $ |V(T)|$ is also even (Since $d(v)$ is odd $\forall v\in T$) ( in this case it can not be  a tree)